# Не получается правильно записать эту формулу

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

[image]

Заданные действительные величины x,y,z,a,b,c,d. Разработать программу, которая упорядочивает величины a,b,c,d так, чтобы a<=b и c<=d, и вычисляет значение функции

```
 if a>b then begin r:=a;a:=b;b:=r;end;
 if c>d then begin r:=c;c:=d;d:=r;end;
 if ((c<=x)and(x<=d))and((c<=y)and(y<=d))
  then
  begin

   if z<>0 then v:=(abs(x)+abs(y))/abs(z);
    end

     begin
     if(x<y) then v:= x+sqrt(sqr(a)+sqr(b));
      if(x>y) then v:= y+sqrt(sqr(a)+sqr(b));
          end
          else
        v:= max(abs(x)+abs(y)+abs(z));
          end;
```

Comment: А ч не понял третью строчку. Максимум от одного значения?

Comment: да там нужно макс только одного значения

Comment: @Lisha "макс только одного значения" - это и есть это одно значение

Comment: `max(abs(x)+abs(y)+abs(z))` - ??

Comment: я так тоже писал не работало я там кусок кода кинув

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот логика упорядочена. Но что делать в последнем случае - непонятно, в формуле ошибка

```
 if ((c <= X) and (X <= d)) and ((c <= Y) and (Y <= d)) then
      if z <> 0 then
         v := (abs(X) + abs(Y)) / abs(z)
      else if (X <= Y) then
         v := X + sqrt(sqr(a) + sqr(b))
      else
         v := Y + sqrt(sqr(a) + sqr(b))
  else
      v := что-то загадочное;
```